# How can DataTable.Rows.Count be different to count of iterations through DataRow

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
DataTable myTable = loadDataTable() // loaded from SQL query in another method
int totalRecords = myTable.Rows.Count;
int recordsProcessed = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Total records: " + totalRecords;
foreach (DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows)
{
    recordsProcessed++;  
    // do some other stuff with each row
}
Console.WriteLine("Processed records: " + recordsProcessed;
```

If the table were to have 1000 rows, I would expect this to give me the following output:

Total records: 1000
Processed records: 1000

For some reason I get a different result - as high as 1.5x the amount of rows - how can this be possible? I have checked and re-checked the code to make sure there is nothing else incrementing the recordsProcessed variable and this is driving me nuts!

Comment: It can't be unless you are adding/removing rows inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Can we see *all* of the code inside of the `foreach loop`?

Comment: I also think your loop needs to change to foreach(DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows){...} otherwise... "Error 16 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: good spot alykins - editing my question now. - DavidG you were right on the money - there were rows being added and totalRecords was not being updated to reflect this. would give you upvote if it wasn't a comment! Thanks for the help.